# Slow uuid_generate performance in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

We are planning to migrate our project from MySql to Postgres. We need Guid as primary key. Some of our table need to insert bulk data. We have noticed slow performance while using UUID in postgres. Below sql is **taking 16 sec**. to generate  10K uuids

`select uuid_generate_v4() from generate_series(1,10000)`

Whereas **Mysql is taking 700 ms.** to generate 100K GUIDs.

I am  missing something ??

**Environment :**

Postgres11 on Windows 10

Comment: What tool are you using to run that query? Does your time measured include displaying the generated IDs? What is the time reported when you using `explain analyze select uuid_generate_v4() from generate_series(1,10000)`? And which kind of UUIDs is MySQL generating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try using the function provided by [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) as stated in the [help page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/uuid-ossp.html) (scroll to the very bottom).

The following query was executed in less than 120 ms on my computer

```
select gen_random_uuid() from generate_series(1,10000)
```

Comment: Good point - that's why I asked what type of UUID MySQL is generating. And [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) seems to indicate the same difference: "*The MAC address of an interface is taken into account only on FreeBSD and Linux. On other operating systems, MySQL uses a randomly generated 48-bit number*". So on Windows it would be a random value, exactly the same as `gen_random_uuid()` from pgcrypto.

Comment: Btw: `explain analyze select gen_random_uuid() from generate_series(1,10000)` only takes 4ms on my Laptop and `explain analyze select uuid_generate_v4() from generate_series(1,10000)` is indeed a lot slower: it needs 3 seconds (which is still far from the 16 seconds mentioned in the question)

Comment: Great ..Thanks .. it tooks  167 msec. for 100000